# Как добраться до SVG checkbox?

Tags: css3

Делаю кастомный checkbox но вот в css не могу добраться до него.

```css
*{
  user-select: none;
}
.filter__parametr{
  display: flex;
  width:300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.filter__block{
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.bl{
  border:3px solid red;
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  display:inline-block;
  vartical-align: middle;
  transform:translateY(3px);
}
#check{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:1px;
  transform:translate(33%,35%);
  opacity:0;
}
input{
    opacity:;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ .bl > #check{
  opacity:1 !important;

}
.filter__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
  color: #888;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px; }

.filter__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888; }

.filter__block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center; }
  .filter__block input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #ababab;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px; }
  .filter__block label {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #888; }
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
  <defs>
<path d="M0,8 8,16 16,0 " fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4px" id="check" /> 
</defs>
</svg>
  <div class="filter__block">
     <label>
      <input id="filter__number-1" type="checkbox">
       <div class="bl">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px">
          <use xlink:href="#check" x="-5px"  y="-6px" width="18px" height="px"/>
        </svg>
       </div>
       10-20 м.кв
      </label>
  </div>
```

Как его чекнуть но только на css без js ?

Comment: А важно именно SVG использовать? Чекнутую "галочку" можно организовать в виде `div:after` , с двумя бордерами и перевернутым на 45 градусов...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME  да я понимаю ..просто охота добраться до SVG  тем более там просто opacity а вот не могу добраться ...js не нужен наверно

Answer (score 0):

Я изначально допустил ошибку в вызове SVGшки ..

Ошибка была в том что я чекал то что находится в теге svg>defs

В общем рабочий вариант вот такой

```css
*{
  user-select: none;
}
.filter__parametr{
  display: flex;
  width:300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.filter__block{
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.bl{
  border:3px solid red;
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  display:inline-block;
  vartical-align: middle;
  transform:translateY(6px);
}
#check{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:1px;
  transform:translate(33%,35%);
}
#ch1{
  opacity:0;
}
input{
    opacity:0;
}
#ch1{
  stroke-dasharray:0;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;  
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .bl{
  border-color:green;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .bl > #ch1{
  opacity:1;
  fill:green;
  animation: draw 0.30s ease-in;
  stroke:green;

}
@keyframes draw{
  from{
   stroke-dasharray:70;
   stroke-dashoffset:70;
   stroke:green;
  }
}
.filter__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
  color: #888;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px; }

.filter__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888; }

.filter__block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center; }
  .filter__block input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #ababab;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px; }
  .filter__block label {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #888; }
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <path d="M0,8 8,16 16,0 " fill="none" stroke-width="4px" id="check"/> 
</defs>
</svg>

<div class="filter__parametr">
  
  <div class="filter__block">
     <label>
      <input id="filter" type="checkbox">
       <div class="bl">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" id="ch1">
          <use xlink:href="#check" x="-5px"  y="-6px" width="18px" height="16px" />
        </svg>
       </div>
       10-20 м.кв
      </label>
  </div>
  
 

</div>
```